# Adding textfields and slider bars to a table in HTML/JADE

Tags: html, slider, pug, textfield

I currently have a handful of sliders next to their corresponding labels and textfields which interact with one another accordingly and ultimately send off their data. While this does the job, I would like it to look more orderly, and I think a table would do quite nicely; however, I'm stumped when it comes to adding the slider bars and textfields to this ideal table of mine. My code is as follows:

```
            Control Panel
    br
    label Max Retry Count (0 - 5)
    input.maxRetryInput(type='text', value='#{max_retry}')
    input.maxRetry(type='range', min='0', max='5', step='1')
    br
    br
    label Scan Frequency Seconds (1 - 30)
    input.scanFrequencyInput(type='text', value='#{scan_freq}')
    input.scanFrequency(type='range', min='1', max='30', step='1')
    br
    br
    label Max Sleep Time (0 - 10)
    input.maxSleepInput(type='text', value='#{max_sleep}')
    input.maxSleep(type='range', min='0', max='10', step='1')
    br
    br
    label Max RSSI Change ( 1 - 100)
    input.maxRSSIChangeInput(type='text', value='#{max_rssiC}')
    input.maxRSSIChange(type='range', min='1', max='100', step='1')
    br
    br
    label Max RSSI History Length (1 - 20)
    input.maxRSSIHistoryInput(type='text', value='#{max_rssiH}')
    input.maxRSSIHistory(type='range', min='1', max='20', step='1')
    br
    br
    label RSSI Coefficient (0 - 2)
    input.RSSICoefficientInput(type='text', value='#{rssi}')
    input.RSSICoefficient(type='range', min='0', max='2', step='0.001')
    br
    br
    label Scans Per Report (1 - 20)
    input.scansPerReportInput(type='text', value='#{scan_per}')
    input.scansPerReport(type='range', min='1', max='20', step='1')
```

It looks like this: [image: le Table]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
h3 Control Panel
table
  tr
    td
      label Max Retry Count (0 - 5)
    td
      input.maxRetryInput(type='text', value='#{max_retry}')
    td
      input.maxRetry(type='range', min='0', max='5', step='1')
  tr
    td
      label Scan Frequency Seconds (1 - 30)
    td
       input.scanFrequencyInput(type='text', value='#{scan_freq}')
    td
       input.scanFrequency(type='range', min='1', max='30', step='1')
(etc.)
```

You could also do this in a [mixin](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html):

```
mixin control-panel(fields)
  table
    each field in fields
      tr
        td
          label= field.label
        td
          input(name= field.name value= field.value)
        td
          input(type='range', min= field.slider.min, max= field.slider.max, step='1')
```

Which would be called like this in the template:

```
+control-panel([
  {
    "name": "max_retry",
    "label": "Max Retry Count (0 - 5)",
    "slider": {
      "min": 0,
      "max": 5
    }
  }
])
```

The mixin takes an array of objects which are easier to configure (and debug) than setting everything up as element properties.